# Calculate the variance of $X \text{~} Pascal(m,p)$

Tags: probability

Calculate the variance of $X \text{~} Pascal(m,p)$.

I know that $\operatorname{Var}(X) = E[X^2] - [EX]^2$, and that $X$ can be thought of as $m$ independent geometric random variables.  This leads to $[EX]^2 = (\frac{m}{p})^2$.  But I'm confused for $E[X^2]$.

By the multinomial theorem:

$E[X^2] = mE[X_i^2]$ for an arbitrary $i$ in $\{1, ..., m\}$  $+ \binom{m}{2}4E[X_jX_k]$ for arbitrary $j$ and $k$ in $\{1, ..., m\}$.

But can I replace $X_jX_k$ with any $X_q^2$ and evaluate normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your last question, note that the $X_j$ and $X_k$ are independent so $E[X_j X_k] = E[X_j] E[X_k]$.

You can continue with your approach (computing $E[X^2]$) and you will get the right answer. However, it may be slightly easier to work with the variance directly. Since the $X_i$ are independent, we have $\operatorname{Var}(X) = \operatorname{Var}(X_1)+\cdots+\operatorname{Var}(X_m)$, and you can use the variance of your geometric distribution. Note that the above variance formula is a consequence of your "multinomial theorem."